# Custom attribute isn't resolved in theme

Tags: android

I've got custom implementation of dialog, which uses different themes for Holo and Material version. The theme is set by custom attribute:

```
<attr name="klAlertDialogTheme" format="reference"/>
```

This attribute is used in custom theme:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light">       
    <item name="klAlertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.KLAlertDialog.Material.Light.Brand</item>
</style>
```

Then I try to get value referenced by attribute:

```
protected KLAlertDialog(final Context context) {
    this(context, resolveDialogTheme(context, 0));
}

static int resolveDialogTheme(final Context context, final int resId) {
    if (resId >= 0x01000000) {
        return resId;
    } else {
        final TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.klAlertDialogTheme,
                outValue, true);
        return outValue.resourceId;
    }
}
```

But sometimes attribute isn't resolved and return empty outValue without actual values. I checked context and theme, context was Activity and theme was correct.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why have you declared `outValue ` as final?

Comment: @Greengoblin because it is never changed

Comment: But its members do. Can you please change it to non-final and see it works?

Comment: @Greengoblin it's just reference, with final we can't change reference, but can change object state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that my Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light theme was overridden by default Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.